# How to create a JavaFX Scene for multiple Key Listeners?

Tags: java, javafx, keylistener

so I am trying to create a Tron mulitplayer game, which is a bit like snake. 
Anyways multiple people should be able to play that game using one keyboard, but diffrent key combinations to steer their character on the screen. One player would currently use the WASD Keys and the other one should use the arrow keys.

My problem is that I have created a scene with Javafx Scene Builder using an FXML. Only after creating the game I have noticed that the scene builder is apparently only supporting one key listener, so at the moment only one player can control their game figure.
Is there any way to fix that? Please help so one player can use the WASD-Keys and the other one can use the arrow keys to navigate.
MY question is diffrent from the existing solutions as the snakes need to belong to diffrent players. It is not sufficient to just check if a key input was pressed or two were pressed simultaneously, but it needs to check if the correct player pressed the input, even if another player pressed their input at that time too.
Hope that clears up the confusuion a bit.

Key Listener

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;

import javafx.scene.Scene;

public class Human extends Player implements Runnable{


int keyboardControlsLayout;
Scene scene;

public Human(int stepSize, String colour, int playerNum, Scene scene, 
           int keyboardControlsLayout) {
    super(stepSize, colour, playerNum);
    // keyboardControlsLayout(0) = WASD
    // keyboardControlsLayout(1) = ARROWS
    this.keyboardControlsLayout = keyboardControlsLayout;
    this.scene = scene;

}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    while(this.getSnake().getAlive()) {

        if (keyboardControlsLayout == 1) {
            // use WASD
            System.out.println("wasd");

            scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
                switch (event.getCode()) {
                    case W:
                        snake.setDirection(0);
                        break;
                    case S:
                        snake.setDirection(1);
                        break;
                    case A:
                        snake.setDirection(3);
                        break;
                    case D:
                        snake.setDirection(2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                //System.out.println(event.getCode().toString());
            });


        } else if (keyboardControlsLayout == 0) {
            System.out.println("arrows");
            // use arrow keys
            scene.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
                switch (event.getCode()) {
                    case UP:
                        snake.setDirection(0);
                        break;
                    case DOWN:
                        snake.setDirection(1);
                        break;
                    case LEFT:
                        snake.setDirection(3);
                        break;
                    case RIGHT:
                        snake.setDirection(2);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            });
        }


    }

}
 }
```

Where I create the scene:

```
public void newGame() {
    System.out.println("<----- NEW GAME ----->");
    game = new Game(10, scene, numHumans);
    displayController.setUpDisplay(game);

    timer = new Timeline((new KeyFrame(
            Duration.millis(80),
            event -> {
                try {
                    timerTick();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch 
                                         block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            })));
    timer.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);

    start();
}

private void start() {
// starts game and logic
}


private void loadDisplayFXMLLoader() {
    FXMLLoader displayFXMLLoader = new 
    FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DisplayView.fxml"));

    try {
        scene = new Scene(displayFXMLLoader.load(), 500, 525);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Main.outputError(e);
    }

    displayController = displayFXMLLoader.getController();

}

private void loadScene() {
    this.setScene(scene);
    this.show();

    //error Handling and closing



}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I like to use the idea found [here](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introduction-to-javafx-for-game-development--cms-23835). He uses `ArrayList` for input. I like to use `Set`. When a mapped button is pressed add it to the input. On release, remove it from the input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple key press on JavaFX scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052257/multiple-key-press-on-javafx-scene)

Comment: Its a similar issue to the one you pointed out. But not quite the same as I do not want mutiple keys pressed at the same time. But the listener to potentially react for two players

Comment: I will have a look at that. Thank you Sedrick!

Comment: I have not used @James_D answer in the duplicate but given his history, I would bet it works. I used the first idea on the link I shared. It works fine.

Comment: If you want to see the first idea in action go [here](https://github.com/sedj601/PongFX/tree/master/src/pongfx). Comment out the AI code ->`if (ballSpeedX < 0) {
//                player1.MovePaddle(true, ball.getCenterX(), ball.getCenterY());
//                player2.MovePaddle(false, ball.getCenterX(), ball.getCenterY());
//            }
//            else {
//                player1.MovePaddle(false, ball.getCenterX(), ball.getCenterY());
//                player2.MovePaddle(true, ball.getCenterX(), ball.getCenterY());
//            }`. Use `A`, `Z`, `<-`, and `->` to move paddles.

Comment: Also, I am not a fan of your `Runnable` Player class while using `Timeline`.

Comment: Well it was a quick fix. Not great but it does the trick kind of. I'd rather get rid of it. Just not sure how. My problem is a bit that those values need to be assigned to a specific player. Thats what i have not found yet. So only one of the snakes I created, the one assigned to that player, will move when a key is pressed not both.

Comment: I suggest you take the time to go through that tutorial completely. It's a very good starting point. It has code on GitHub also.

Comment: "_I do not want mutiple keys pressed at the same time. But the listener to potentially react for two players_". I'm not sure I understand your reasoning. If both players can play on the same keyboard simultaneously, then you'll need to handle multiple keys pressed at the same time.

Comment: Yes they need to be able to, but the current tutorials are that those two keys should always be pressed simultaneously. You gave me an idea though :) Cheers

Answer (score -1):

I'm not familiar with FXML but I personally use the javafx myself and it works well. I tweaked an old program to suit your needs if you'd like to try and test it out

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class yeet {

    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JPanel panel;

    private static int x = 300;
    private static int y = 300;
    private static int x1 = 500;
    private static int y1 = 500;

    private static boolean running = true;
    private static boolean moving = false;
    private static boolean moving1 = false;
    private static boolean up;
    private static boolean down;
    private static boolean right;
    private static boolean left;
    private static boolean up1;
    private static boolean down1;
    private static boolean right1;
    private static boolean left1;

    private static Timer refresh;
    private static Timer speed;

    private static Graphics g;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        UI();



        ActionListener al = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if(moving && up) y--;
                if (moving && down) y++;
                if (moving && right) x++;
                if (moving && left) x--;

                if (moving1 && up1) y1--;
                if (moving1 && down1) y1++;
                if (moving1 && right1) x1++;
                if (moving1 && left1) x1--;

                panel.repaint();

            }

        };

        ActionListener al1 = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                guy(g);
                laser(g);

            }

        };

        refresh = new Timer(0, al1);
        refresh.start();
        speed = new Timer (4, al);
        speed.start();



        while (running) {
            guy(g);
            laser(g);

        }

    }

    public static void guy(Graphics g) {
        g = panel.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.drawRect(x, y, 25, 25);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 25, 25);

    }

    public static void laser (Graphics g) {
        g = panel.getGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.drawRect(x1, y1, 30, 30);
        g.fillRect(x1, y1, 30, 30);
    }

    public static void UI () {

        frame = new JFrame("Multiple movement test");
        panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setBackground(Color.black);
        panel.setLayout(null);

        frame.setSize(600,600);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                    moving = true;
                    up = true;

                    down = false;
                    right = false;
                    left = false;

                    refresh.start();
                    speed.start();
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                    moving = true;
                    down = true;

                    up = false;
                    right = false;
                    left = false;

                    refresh.start();
                    speed.start();
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                    moving = true;
                    left = true;

                    up = false;
                    down = false;
                    right = false;

                    refresh.start();
                    speed.start();
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    moving = true;
                    right = true;

                    left = false;
                    up = false;
                    down = false;

                    refresh.start();
                    speed.start();
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
                    moving1 = true;
                    up1 = true;

                    down1 = false;
                    right1 = false;
                    left1 = false;

                    refresh.start();
                    speed.start();
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
                    moving1 = true;
                    left1 = true;

                    up1 = false;
                    down1 = false;
                    right1 = false;


                    refresh.start();
                    speed.start();
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
                    moving1 = true;
                    down1 = true;

                    up1 = false;
                    right1 = false;
                    left1 = false;

                    refresh.start();
                    speed.start();
                }

                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                    moving1 = true;
                    right1 = true;

                    up1 = false;
                    down1 = false;
                    left1 = false;

                    refresh.start();
                    speed.start();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });

        frame.add(panel);

    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you Alex. My problem is that I need to assign some sort of "ownership" to the keys, so snake 1 gets moved by the WASD Keys and snake two gets moved by the arrow ones. I am not sure how to apply that to  what you wrote, but I will think on it.

Comment: No, the question is about FX, not Swing/awt