# how to use KeyEvent inside if condition?

Tags: javafx

using Javafx  i I have Text-area and I want to get new line if user press Shift & Enter

I use  &&  also I used    +

```
private void KeyRelsesed_send(KeyEvent event) {

        if (event.getCode() == (KeyCode.SHIFT && KeyCode.ENTER)) {

            area.appendText("\n");
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple key press on JavaFX scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052257/multiple-key-press-on-javafx-scene)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is a modifier key. The [`KeyEvent`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyEvent.html) class has boolean-returning methods to check if a modifier key is down when another non-modifier key is pressed. If you want to check for <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then you can use:

```
if (event.isShiftDown() && event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
    // Do something...
}
```

Note this will allow other modifier keys to be down as well. If the `// Do something...` code should not be executed if one or more modifier keys other than <kbd>Shift</kbd> are down then you'll have to explicitly check that they're not (e.g. `!event.isAltDown()`). In this case, it may be clearer and easier to implement if you create your own [`KeyCombination`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyCombination.html) and test if the `KeyEvent` matches it.

```
KeyCombination combo = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER, KeyCombination.SHIFT_DOWN);

if (combo.match(event)) {
    // Do something...
}
```

This will require the other modifier keys to be up, according to the documentation of [`KeyCodeCombination`'s constructor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/input/KeyCodeCombination.html#%3Cinit%3E(javafx.scene.input.KeyCode,javafx.scene.input.KeyCombination.Modifier...)):

> Constructs a `KeyCodeCombination` for the specified main key and with the specified list of modifiers. All modifier keys which are not explicitly listed are set to the default `RELEASED` value.

*Note: It says `RELEASED` but they mean `UP`.*

If you need to know about multiple *non-modifier* keys being pressed at the same time, then you need to keep track of which keys have been pressed but not yet released. For that, look at the accepted answer to the [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052257/multiple-key-press-on-javafx-scene) that was [linked by Tarmo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56286805/how-to-use-keyevent-inside-if-condition#comment99186543_56286805).

Comment: Thank you It worked   i make enter for send  and Enter+Shift for new line so I did use if and if else so maybe some one need that