# how to open new instance of app using JavaFX on macOS

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I want to use **JavaFX** to write a **macOS application**, and I want to use `command+n` shotcut to **open new instance** of app.
how to do?

Comment: This should help you with the `command+n` [linkt to post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23052257/multiple-key-press-on-javafx-scene)

Answer (score 0):

Command-N is used to create a new document or view, not a new instance of the application.

What you want to do is assign the Command-N shortcut to a MenuItem that will create a new Window.  Your application will be set to continue running even when the last window.  You do that by calling Platform.setImplicitExit(false)